# Access to remote server for File I/O

Tags: c#, file, io

I have a question about accessing to remote server.
Should I do something special when I want to get into remote server ?
Example path is : \server\directory do I need to use diffrent library than these which I'm using to copy/move normal files ?

I've tried do this this way :

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream( \\server\direcotyr, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None);
```

Not full code, that's just an example.

I'm asking because I have some problem while trying copy these files from server and thought that might be a cause.

Comment: Is this a web application or console application or... ? Also what error are you getting? And is "\\server\direcotyr" in quotes or no?

Comment: Under what protocol can you access that server? Is it a Windows Share and does the user that is executing your program have privilege to read/write to it? Is it NFS share, FTP, SFTP, something else?

Comment: It is sometimes easier to simply mount a drive and access it as a regular folder

Comment: Windows Share i have an access through //server/directory path

Comment: this should work fine if you have access via \\server\share

Comment: You should have a permission on server share folder by admin.

Comment: So this way should work right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example,if it were `@"\\server\direcotyr\filename.fileExtension"` and the calling code had permissions, it should work.